# How can I compute a route/path of a certain length between two places?

Tags: graph, routes, a-star

Given two places in a region, how can I compute a path that is of certain distance (the distance is given as a parameter) which connects the two places. The resulting path should ideally be composed of roads that are visited no more than once.

I have learnt that this problem can be viewed as a graph problem where the roads in the map represent the edges of the graph and the intersection/junctions represent the nodes of the graph. From this the problem can be simplified to finding a path of certain length for any two nodes in the graph.

One of my approaches to this problem can be broken into two steps:

1. Finding the shortest path between the two nodes (using A* or a similar algorithm).
2. Extending/Expanding the shortest path that is returned from A* so that it's long enough.

Now, I am not exactly sure if this approach is worth pursuing or if a better approach exists? Also, I've not come across any methods that would allow me to expand the path - are there any specific techniques that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use an ad-hoc heuristic function. The goal state should be reaching the destination with a path long L. (So if you reach the destination with a too short path the goal test is not satisfied and the algorithm will continue).

```
#goal state
if (state == dest and curr_length == required_length)
    return path
```

For every other node the heuristic must give a value that is a combination of the expected distance from the destination and the required length that must still be travelled.

```
h(state, curr_length):
    dist = manhattan_distance(state, goal)

    #must use the abs instead if curr_length > required_length this value becomes
    #negative and this node gets a wrong result
    len = abs(required_length - curr_length)

    return dist + len
```

I'm not sure if this heuristic is consistent or not, but you can try with something like this and check the results.
If this search work it should also be optimal.